# Meaning of と思ったら (Colloquial)

Tags: particle-と

Example 1:
(After visiting long lost friend)

> やれやれ、 いきなり どこに連れていかれるか**と思ったら**。。。

Example 2:
(Girl comes to boy's apartment to wake him up for school)

> Boy: なんでお前がここにいるんだ？
>
> Girl: 起こしに来てあげたの。時々様子を見ておいてっておばあさんから鍵を預かってたから。
>         インターホンを押してもぜんぜん出ない**と思ったら**。。。

Is there something omitted after と思ったら? What does it mean?

Comment: Related... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/phrase-translation-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0

Comment: 限りなくduplicateに近い気がする……！

Comment: Actually, I was thinking the second example is a slightly different usage.
"インターホンを押してもぜんぜん出ない" isn't a question but a thought. So maybe this means "As I thought you wouldn't answer even if rang the intercom... ( I used the key)?. Unless なんで...か is omitted, I can't see how it could mean "wondering" like in the linked question. This thought would also answer his question as to why she was in his room.

Comment: @aproofro か is irrelevant to this idiom and と思ったら（思えば） part alone can tell this nuance.