# Meaning of 噂を聞かないと思ったら

Tags: grammar, negation, conditionals

In a manga, two American boxers are talking about a guy they used to know who now lives in Japan.

> Boxer A: あのブルドッグがリングに上がるって本当かよ。
>
> Boxer B: ああ。ここ数年噂を聞かねェと思ったらボクサーになってたんだよ。日本でな。

I think 数年〜の噂を聞かない means "I haven't heard of 〜 for some years", so maybe the rough translation of the sentence is "I haven't heard of him for some years, it seems that he's become a boxer". But what is the meaning of 思ったら here? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, your assessment that:

> 数年〜の噂を聞かない

Roughly means:

> I haven't heard of 〜 for some years

Is accurate. [噂を聞く](http://jisho.org/search/uwasawokiku) is a set phrase that typically means "to hear something about", and doesn't imply negativity the same way "hearing rumors about someone" does in English.

Moving on to `思ったら`, [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30587/7705) is at least somewhat related, although the linked answer focuses much more on the omitted clause than on the usage of `思ったら`.

That said, I would think of this sentence:

> ここ数年噂を聞かねェと思ったらボクサーになってたんだよ。

Roughly like this:

> Just when I was thinking I hadn't heard anything about 〜 for a couple years now, it turns out he's become a boxer in Japan.

Much the same way we do this with "think" in English, one can use conditional conjugations of 思う to express that an outcome is novel and/or contrary to what the speaker is expecting.