# What are the various 'unuttered' phrases or sentences that Japanese omit in everyday conversation and/or narration?

Tags: orthography, sentence-final-particles, conversations

While translating a book I come across the following sentence.

> 女の子の注意を逸{そ}らすことができれば.....

Research into the [ba ending](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/phrase-translation-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0) allowed me to discover that the above is a 'unfinished' sentence. This in turn made me wonder, what are the various 'unuttered' phrases or sentences that Japanese omit in everyday conversation and/or narration, like the above statement?

Comment: You just have to figure it out through experience, deduction, and the surrounding context. Your link clearly shows the context that should lead you to an easy answer regarding the nature of the 'unuttered' clause. This is the same with any language, therefore I'm voting to close this question due to lack of pertinence to the Japanese language in particular.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not specifically pertain to the Japanese language.

Comment: A possible answer.  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/phrase-translation-何を言い出すかと思えば

Comment: @BJCUAI Excuse me for not being well-knowledge enough to figure it out on my own, even with the provided context. I am unfamiliar with what is normally unuttered in Japanese conversations, due to being a foreigner. So in order to learn more about unuttered statements that pertain to Japanese culture, I asked the above question.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey One could translate the unfinished portion to 'I can strike first', 'it would give me the advantage', 'I can make it through this alive', etc.. The only thing we can be relatively sure about, from the context, is that it would be something the protagonist would benefit from.   Asking, however, for a way to figure out unfinished sentences by yourself, increased exposure to the language is the best way. Look for more information, like [this](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2016/05/09/language/complete-japanese-speaker-leave-sentences-incomplete/#.XW2aRyhKiUl) and other examples..

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Also, there's no need to apologize, as most every Japanese learner has eventually had to grapple with this issue and eventually overcome it. Hang in there ;)

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Please phrase the question as a question in the title :)

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Try searching incomplete sentences.

Comment: https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2016/05/09/language/complete-japanese-speaker-leave-sentences-incomplete/#.XXFq3ChKjIU