# Meaning of 思えば in 誰かと思えば

Tags: translation, conditionals

The context of the phrase is that two have not met in a long time just meet up and are talking to each other, the conversation goes like this:

Person 1 (The one who started the conversation): 久しぶりだな

Person 2: おやおや、**誰かと思えば**

In the sentence "誰かと思えば" I know that 思えば is on the conditional form, but there's no condition, so what is the meaning of the ば form on this sentence?

Comment: **Context is key.** Without context, it is very difficult to explain many things.

Comment: Possibly related: [Phrase translation: 何を言い出すかと思えば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30586/41067)

Comment: Yea, I could copy and paste the accepted answer from the above link to this question.